# my dataframe contains '/' in column name , How can i plot certain column values in that column name?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i need to plot the state called 'kerala' in the column 'state/unionterritory' and 'confirmed' to create a lineplot.

so far I have written till

[1](https://www.kaggle.com/essentialguy/exercise-final-project)`sns.lineplot(x=my_data['state/unionterritory'],y=my_data['confirmed'])`

[https://www.kaggle.com/essentialguy/exercise-final-project]

[this is the dataframe.head() , see the column name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iSGT.png)

Comment: you forgot `'` after `/unionterritory`

Comment: sorry typing mistake, tell me how to display specific column values for plotting

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to get a column `state/unionterritory` from your `DataFrame` and filter it so it contains only `Kerala` state:

```
my_data_kerala = my_data[my_data['state/unionterritory'] == 'Kerala']['state/unionterritory']
```